# Cascading-Hadoop: isSafe() in Operation

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading

> Returns true if this Operation instance can safely execute on the same
>   'record' multiple times, false otherwise. That is, this Operation is
>   safe if it has no side-effects, or if it does, they are idempotent.
>
> If seeing the same 'record' more than once can cause errors
>   (internally or externally), this method must return false.
>   http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/javadoc/cascading/operation/Operation.html#isSafe()

What is the meaning of *can safely execute on the same 'record' multiple times*?

At first I thought the meaning is it's a pure function. But is it? What is the meaning of idempotent?

What is the example of unsafe operation? The description told about safely execute on the same record. What kind of operation that can't operate safely on same record?